# Error in Netbeans(?): attribute column name (length) is a reserved Java Persistence QL keyword

Tags: jpa

I have a column named `length` in an Oracle database.  I cannot change the column name. When I use the `@Column(name="length")` in a JPA Entity I get the following error:

> attribute column name (length) is a
>   reserved Java Persistence QL keyword

I am using the Netbeans 6.8 IDE.

Any ideas on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, escaping the column name in double quotes should work.

```
@Column(name="\"length\"")
private int length;
```